# verify_upload not working in Candy Machine v2

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I just finished uploading my test nfts onto arweave using the devnet. This was the code I used:

```
ts-node D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k C:/Users/Cardo/.config/solana/Test/seller.json -cp D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/config.json D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/TB-Assets
```

I followed the documentation but when I got to verify upload, it says the "verify_command" is unknown. This is the code I used when I tried to run it:

```
ts-node D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts verify_upload -e devnet -k C:/Users/Cardo/.config/solana/Test/seller.json -cp D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/config.json -c D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/.cache/devnet-temp.json
```

I've checked for any spelling errors or extra spaces or anything that could make a difference but I'm not sure what could be causing the problem. Thank you guys for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ts-node D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts verify_upload -e devnet -k C:/Users/Cardo/.config/solana/Test/seller.json -c D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/.cache/devnet-temp.json
```

without

```
-cp D:/Hashlips/Test-Metaplex-master/js/packages/cli/config.json
```

You don't need the config in the verification. Just the reference in your Cache.

As in: https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/verify-upload